# TFS build does not have the same output as file system web publish

Tags: asp.net, tfs, tfsbuild

I normally do a file system publish on my asp web applications before deploying in them on the web root of my web server myself and visual studio packages my aspx pages seperately along with my apis and libraries into DLLs nicely.

I was wondering how to achieve the same effects with Team Build. As of now, I'm able to run build definitions with the default template and the output I'd gotten are just the binaries DLLs without any aspx pages being generated at all

http://postimg.org/image/occoo03zh/

However I'm getting just the DLLs without web pages in Team Build

http://postimg.org/image/mat7co6vp/

I had tried passing various MSBuild Arguments in hopes that it would have changed the output, but no luck thus far. Anyone knows the exact reasons and ways that I can resolve this? Is this output from TFS build normal?

It hasn't been resolved yet, any insights is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Asp pages are not compiled, your compiled dll's will be outputted to the binaries directory, but your asp pages will be left in the sources directory. you will need to add a post build activity to copy your asp structure into the drop folder.

Can you confirm this by looking in the build workspace (on build server) and seeing if the structure is correct in the sources directory and that the dll's were created in the bin folder. if so you can then copy that whole structure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The 2 images that I linked consisted of the output that I want, which encapsulates the aspx pages and the dlls in the bin and the current output that I'm getting from TFS build, which is only the dlls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass MSbuild some arguments to get it to generate the published website as you would see it with a file system publish.  See [here](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/building-websites-team-foundation-build-2015/) for something similar done with Visual Studio Online.

```
/p:OutDir=$(build.stagingDirectory) /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
```